# Undefined property: Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator::$id. It says the problem is in my index

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

Hello I have a problem with Paginator dont know how I can make it work.

This is my ReportsController:

```
public function index()
    {
        //Show all created reports
        $reports = Reports::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(15);
        return view('reports.index', ['reports'=>compact('reports')])->with(['reports', $reports]);
    }
```

And this is the index.blade.php:

```
@foreach($reports  as $report)
         <tr>
             <td scope="row"><a href="/reports/show">{{$report->id}}</td>
             <td>{{$report->title}}</td>
             <td>{{$report->category}}</td>
             <td>{{$report->name}}</td>
             <td>{{$report->created_at}}</td>
             <td>{{$report->updated_at}}</td>
         </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen every method of passing data to the view used in a single attempt. For reference: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#passing-data-to-views The answer below is correct, but have a read of the Docs; they're pretty comprehensive :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return view('reports.index', ['reports' => $reports]);
// or
return view('reports.index', compact('reports'));
```

What you had was this:

```
['reports' => ['reports' => $reports]]
```

If you were going to use `with` it would be:

```
...->with('reports', $reports);
// or
...->with(['reports' => $reports]);
```

Comment: thnx alot really helped

Comment: @Strike no problem, if it helped you please feel free to vote it up as well :)